# CRM 2011 solution says components are missing, but they are actually in the system

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've been trying to import a custom solution into a separate organisation. On export I get the warning about required components but I know that they are already in there, albeit from a separate managed solution.

When I try to import the solution it fails and lists the components it needs but are missing. I have checked again for some of them and they are definitely there, so I don't know why it is failing.

Is it because they weren't created in the organization itself but from a separate solution? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is the separate managed solution in both orgs?

Comment: Both orgs have them both in, but in one they are unmanaged as that is where we are developing them and we're importing them into the other as managed

Comment: Have you tried to add the required components in the solution file? http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/crm/thread/0e745ca3-4a50-4018-8f9b-f0eadb3b7d40

Comment: I've tried doing that, and while i can get round it that way each thing i add requires something else so the solution size just keeps growing. What i'd like to do is keep the solutions to only what they need to contain, but then i've got this problem

Answer (score 2):

I have run into a similar issue with field level security profiles - the component is clearly both in the solution I am trying to import as well as in the org in another solution.
I would recommend checking the "Missing Dependencies" in the solution.xml file and you will be able to see all of the components that are considered a dependency.  I was able to find the 3 missing dependencies that the system was complaining about.  Somehow the FieldSecurityProfileId in the import file did not match the id of the one in the system (someone may have gone in and re-created it, thus creating a new id).  I was able to resolve my issue by re-importing my version (managed) of the solution where the component already existed so that the correct id got put into the system and then the import worked.

Comment: Is there any way to get round it if the component is included in another managed solution already imported into the organisation, but not included in the solution I am trying to import? Our initial plan was to create and export components in small solutions, but with things being related to each other over solutions, it looks like this might not be possible